# Delete a redirect in wordpress database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, redirect, phpmyadmin

I had an information page as a top level page in wordpress. It was then moved to be a sub page of another there wordpress created a redirect for this url.

I have now re-created this page as a top level page. This will become an aplpication whereas the old sub page will remain in tact as an informational resource.

I am writing a script for logging in to the application however when logged in I have used a php header("Location: /"); pointing to the new url. For some reason it redirects to the old page. Is there a way to delete a re-direct from phpmyadmin?

Thank you!

Comment: header("Location: /") will not work if any html output is printed to the page. and if you're getting this line from db, it probably won't work. What does your script look like?

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress you can do the normal fetching of data from database which is

```
 $query = "select this from database";
 $result = mysql_result(mysql_query($query), 0);
```

redirection in wordpress is the bloginfo();
example:

```
 <a href="<?php echo bloginfo('url')?>/path/to/something">Link</a>
```

I don't really know your script so I can not give you the complete answer, but hopefully you will do this yourself because you have the code for the redirection and fetching of data